# How can I abort an htmx request?

Tags: htmx

I have some dynamically created form fields which I'm using to set parameters for a htmx hx-get request in htmx:configRequest:

```
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', function(evt) { 
// setting parameters here with evt.detail.parameters["key"] = value; 
})
```

While looping through my inputs, if any of them are empty, I want to abort the request, and alert the user. I've tried calling

```
evt.detail.xhr.abort();
```

but I just get the error "Uncaught TypeError: evt.detail.xhr is undefined. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

That event is triggered before the ajax request. To cancel the request at that point use `evt.preventDefault()`